# Set x axis to plotly Gantt chart

Tags: python, plot, plotly

I'm new to plotly and I have some tasks with start=int and finish=int (in abstract time units). But x axis is in date format as default. I want to set x axis in number format(0,1,2...)

Here is my code:

```
    df=list(df.values())
    pprint(df)
    colors = ['#ff1919', '#0000ff']
    fig = ff.create_gantt(df, colors=colors, index_col='Resource', 
    reverse_colors=True, show_colorbar=True)
    py.plot(fig, filename='gantt-string-variable', world_readable=True)
```

df looks like:

```
df=[{'Finish': 5, 'Resource': 'Red', 'Start': 0, 'Task': 'task1'},
 {'Finish': 13, 'Resource': 'Red', 'Start': 5, 'Task': 'task2'},
 {'Finish': 8, 'Resource': 'Blue', 'Start': 5, 'Task': 'task3'},
 {'Finish': 11, 'Resource': 'Blue', 'Start': 5, 'Task': 'task4'},
 {'Finish': 20, 'Resource': 'Red', 'Start': 13, 'Task': 'task5'},
 {'Finish': 19, 'Resource': 'Blue', 'Start': 13, 'Task': 'task6'},
 {'Finish': 24, 'Resource': 'Red', 'Start': 20, 'Task': 'task7'}]
```

any advice!

Answer (score 5):

Call this line `fig['layout']['xaxis'].update({'type': None})` before `py.plot(fig, filename='gantt-string-variable', world_readable=True)`.

Comment: Thanks for answer :)

Comment: Thanks for this answer!